# No overload matches for this call, extra custom prop of styled component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop, styled-components

> No overload matches for this call

For props ***x, y*** in `StyledContainer`, it's throwing "No overload matches for this call".

[image: Here is the main error throwing on build]

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

interface Props {
  onDragStart?: () => void;
  onDragEnd?: () => void;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  isDragging: boolean;
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  onDrag?: (position: { translateX: number; translateY: number }) => void;
}
interface State {
  originalX: number;
  originalY: number;
  lastTranslateX: number;
  lastTranslateY: number;
  translateX: number;
  translateY: number;
  isDragging: boolean;
}
export default class EventRecap extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    isDragging: false,

    originalX: 0,
    originalY: 0,

    translateX: 0,
    translateY: 0,

    lastTranslateX: 0,
    lastTranslateY: 0,
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp);
  }

  handleMouseDown = ({
    clientX,
    clientY,
  }: {
    clientX: number;
    clientY: number;
  }) => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp);

    if (this.props.onDragStart) {
      this.props.onDragStart();
    }

    this.setState({
      originalX: clientX,
      originalY: clientY,
      isDragging: true,
    });
  };

  handleMouseMove = ({
    clientX,
    clientY,
  }: {
    clientX: number;
    clientY: number;
  }) => {
    const { isDragging } = this.state;
    const { onDrag } = this.props;

    if (!isDragging) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        translateX: clientX - prevState.originalX + prevState.lastTranslateX,
        translateY: clientY - prevState.originalY + prevState.lastTranslateY,
      }),
      () => {
        if (onDrag) {
          onDrag({
            translateX: this.state.translateX,
            translateY: this.state.translateY,
          });
        }
      },
    );
  };

  handleMouseUp = () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp);

    this.setState(
      {
        originalX: 0,
        originalY: 0,
        lastTranslateX: this.state.translateX,
        lastTranslateY: this.state.translateY,

        isDragging: false,
      },
      () => {
        if (this.props.onDragEnd) {
          this.props.onDragEnd();
        }
      },
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { translateX, translateY, isDragging } = this.state;
    return (
      <StyledContainer
        x={translateX}
        y={translateY}
        isDragging={isDragging}
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
      >
       {children}
  
      </StyledContainer>
    );
  }
}

const StyledContainer = styled.div.attrs<Props>((props) => ({
  style: { transform: `translate(${props.x}px, ${props.y}px)` },
}))`
  cursor: grab;
  ${({ isDragging }: { isDragging: boolean }) =>
    isDragging &&
    css`
      opacity: 0.8;
      cursor: grabbing;
    `};
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using [attributes merging](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) with `styled.div.attrs<Props>`, directly use [custom props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props) so that they are exposed as the styled component props definition as well:

```
// Add the custom Props as a TypeScript type argument to styled.div
// https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props
const StyledContainer2 = styled.div<Props>`
  cursor: grab;
  /* Directly adapt style based on props, instead of merging attributes
  https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props */
  transform: ${(props) => css`translate(${props.x}px, ${props.y}px)`};
  ${({
    // No need to redefine type, it is directly taken from the custom props type argument of styled.div
    isDragging
  }) =>
    isDragging
      ? css`
          opacity: 0.8;
          cursor: grabbing;
        `
      : ""};
`;
```

Then you can use these props directly inside the style block and [adapt style based on props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) (instead of the attributes merging).

Another advantage is that the props typing is directly available when you interpolate your function, so there is no need to redefine the props type.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-rgb-oomc6n?file=/src/App.tsx:330-972

Comment: Solved! I owe you sir! Thanks mate <3